# How can I prevent that visitors set fullcalendar (arshaw) to editable:true via firebug?

Tags: fullcalendar

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/editable/

The option editable can be manipulatet by visistors of my site via firebug and change data in my database. Is there a solution?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            editable: false,
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really, though [minifying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) should get you close enough for most people to give up.

However, even if you minify and obfuscate it, someone determined enough will be able to de-obfuscate and reverse it.

There is a reason why the mantra of "never trust the client" is so often repeated. You need to add server side checks to the data to ensure that it is consistent and as expected, if this is a real worry.

Answer (score 1):

If someone cares enough it will only be modified in their window, if you don't handle the changes to write them to your database the next visitor will see the same calendar as you have configured.